# SQL: Select data from Parent table and sum columns from two Children tables in output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a parent table that has two tables of child data as well as a couple of referencing tables. (Only relevant data shown for simplicity)

[image]

Sample Data: ShiftAnalysis

```
+----+------------+-----+
| Id | StartTime  | Hrs |
+----+------------+-----+
|  1 | 2018-02-01 |   8 |
|  2 | 2018-02-02 |   8 |
|  3 | 2018-02-03 |   8 |
|  4 | 2018-02-04 |  12 |
+----+------------+-----+
```

Sample Data: ShiftAnalysisItems

```
+----+-----------+---------+---------------+------------+
| Id | SetupTime | RunTime | ShiftAnalysis | SalesOrder |
+----+-----------+---------+---------------+------------+
|  1 |        60 |     400 |             1 |       7018 |
|  2 |        30 |     450 |             2 |       7019 |
|  3 |        60 |     120 |             3 |       7020 |
|  4 |        60 |     240 |             3 |       7021 |
|  5 |        15 |     195 |             4 |       7022 |
|  6 |        15 |     195 |             4 |       7022 |
+----+-----------+---------+---------------+------------+
```

Sample Data: ShiftAnalysisDownTimeItems

```
+----+------------------+---------------+------------+
| Id | DownTimeDuration | ShiftAnalysis | SalesOrder |
+----+------------------+---------------+------------+
|  1 |               20 |             1 |       7018 |
|  2 |               30 |             4 |       7022 |
|  3 |               30 |             4 |       7022 |
+----+------------------+---------------+------------+
```

What I'd like to do is Select:

```
ShiftAnalysis.StartTime
ShiftAnaylsys.ManHours
Employee.Name
SUM(ShiftAnalysisItems.RunTime)
SUM(ShiftAnalysisItems.SetupTime)
SUM(ShiftAnalysisDownTimeItems.DownTimeDuration)
```

I have created this T-SQL:

```
Select 
    StartTime, 
    ManHours,
    emp.Name as Employee,
    (Select Sum(RunTime) from ShiftAnalysisItems as sai join ShiftAnalysis as sa1 on sai.ShiftAnalysisItem_ShiftAnalysis = sa1.Id where sa1.Id = sa.Id) as RunTime,
    (Select Sum(SetupTime) from ShiftAnalysisItems as sai join ShiftAnalysis as sa1 on sai.ShiftAnalysisItem_ShiftAnalysis = sa1.Id where sa1.Id = sa.Id) as SetupTime,
    (Select Sum(DownTimeDuration) from ShiftAnalysisDownTimeItems as dti join ShiftAnalysis as sa1 on dti.ShiftAnalysisDownTimeItem_ShiftAnalysis = sa1.Id where sa1.Id = sa.Id) as DownTime
from 
    ShiftAnalysis as sa
join 
    Employees as emp on sa.ShiftAnalysis_Employee = emp.Id
join 
    Machines as m on sa.ShiftAnalysis_Machine = m.Id
join 
    MachineTypes as mt on m.Machine_MachineType = mt.Id
Where
    mt.Description = 'Print'
Order By
    StartTime
```

This is a snippet of the output:

```
+------------+----------+------------+---------+-----------+----------+
| StartTime  | ManHours |  Employee  | RunTime | SetupTime | DownTime |
+------------+----------+------------+---------+-----------+----------+
| 2018-01-02 | 12.00    | Employee 1 | 190.00  | 215.00    |      315 |
| 2018-01-02 | 7.50     | Employee 2 | NULL    | NULL      |      450 |
| 2018-01-02 | 7.50     | Employee 3 | NULL    | NULL      |      450 |
| 2018-01-02 | 9.00     | Employee 4 | 170.00  | 70.00     |      300 |
| 2018-01-02 | 9.00     | Employee 4 | 170.00  | 70.00     |      300 |
| 2018-01-03 | 7.50     | Employee 2 | 165.00  | 100.00    |      185 |
+------------+----------+------------+---------+-----------+----------+
```

My problem is that it only seemingly shows records where there is downtime. Not every ShiftAnalysis record has DowTime Children.

Also, it looks like I need to group those inline selects because as you can see with Employee 4 above, it shows it twice. I've tried grouping the inline queries but I just cannot get my head around it and nothing seem favourable so far. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the query below, try LEFT OUTER JOIN instead if sub-queries:

```
SELECT 
    StartTime, 
    ManHours,
    emp.Name AS Employee,
    SUM(ISNUL(RunTime,0)) AS RunTime,
    SUM(ISNUL(SetupTime,0)) AS SetupTime,
    SUM(ISNUL(DownTimeDuration,0)) AS DownTime
FROM 
    ShiftAnalysis AS sa
INNER JOIN
    Employees AS emp ON sa.ShiftAnalysis_Employee = emp.Id
INNER JOIN
    Machines AS m ON sa.ShiftAnalysis_Machine = m.Id
INNER JOIN
    MachineTypes AS mt ON m.Machine_MachineType = mt.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ShiftAnalysisItems AS sai ON sa.Id = sai.ShiftAnalysisItem_ShiftAnalysis
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ShiftAnalysisDownTimeItems  AS dti ON sa.Id = dti.ShiftAnalysisDownTimeItem_ShiftAnalysis
WHERE
    mt.Description = 'Print'
GROUP BY 
    StartTime, ManHours,  emp.Name 
ORDER BY
    StartTime
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately this doesn't show any ShiftAnalysis records that do not have ShiftAnalysisDownTimeItems. Also the RuntTime's are huge. I'd need to look further into it but it looks like it's summing more than it should.

Comment: @paulpitchford That is strange because the LEFT OUTER JOIN makes sure of that.

Comment: On closer inspection you were right. Thank you for your help.